# new XSLTProcessor() fails in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, xml, lwc-oss

I am playing around a bit with lwc and the open-source version of it. I tried to copy my open source lwc component into my saleforce project but now I am getting an error message that does not really help:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import testXml from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/testXml';
import testXslt from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/testXslt';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {

    renderedCallback() {
        const xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(testXslt);
        const result = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(testXml, document);

        this.template.querySelector('.container').appendChild(result);
    }
}
```

outside SF it worked flawlessly, but now it breaks already with `new XSLTProcessor()` telling me that:

```
TypeError: XSLTProcessor constructor: 'new' is required
```

I already figured out, that the XSLTProcessor might fail to load in some browsers as the [documentations states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor), but since it worked outside SF I am confused now, and the message does not really help.

Does anyone understand the root cause and reason for the message or does anyone know another method to process the xXMLwithin lwc? (should I try aura?)

Comment: From the error message, looks like the compiler is unable to find the XSLTProcessor class and hence, throwing an error asking you to declare the constructor. May be you need to include an import statement to explicitly indicate the open source lwc component in your salesforce project.

Comment: what do you mean I have to import? the os-lwc component is a copy of the component above, and it is working outside the sf scope.

Comment: Assuming that the os-lwc component as another ES6 module, my guess is that myComponent.js file is unable to identify it without an explicit import instruction. Consider this os-lwc component like a shared JS file or service utility JS. The code could be some this like `import {importStylesheet, transformToFragment} from 'c\os-lwc.js'` or `import {importStylesheet, transformToFragment} from '..\..\os-lwc.js'`. Its just my guess. You could give it a try.

[Take a look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_share_code]

Comment: import statements are not limited to lightning platform. Its an ES6 standard. so, it doesn't matter if the component is within or outside the sf scope.

Comment: The XSLTProcessor is part of js and in Experimental state in most of the browsers. So I don*t have the code to process my XML/XSLT. I just want to use the existing js class, but somehow I am not having acces under SF circumstances, but only in a os environment.

Comment: I guess I misread the question. I see what you are trying to do. Looking at the LWC source code (https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/tree/master/packages/lwc), I don't think XSLT Processing has been included yet as a part of this framework. One idea would be to include open source XSLT libraries as a service utility and refer to that in your code, but that would require including a lot of dependencies and lot more files in your project. Not sure if that's worth the effort. Is the requirement something that cannot be done with child components, instead of XML/ XSLT based approach?

Comment: Did you get any solution here? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Shaggy no, sorry :( Did you meanwhile find any workaround?

Comment: Check out this -> https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000ISQpQAO & https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/2069 Looks like they fixed it in Spring'21 Release.